# .NET, Silverlight Outlook COM. What methods/properties do i have?

Tags: .net, silverlight, com, outlook

If i do something like var v = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Outlook.Application"); in .NET it creates me a usable object.

My question is how do i know what properties and methods i have on this object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the Outlook object model documentation on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff870599(v=office.14).aspx